# How do I take gradients of MultibodyPlant computations w.r.t. mass, center-of-mass, inertia, etc.?

Tags: python-3.x, drake, autodiff, system-identification

I see the current chapter of [Underactuated: System Identification](http://underactuated.csail.mit.edu/sysid.html) and the corresponding notebook, and it currently does it through symbolics.

I'd like to try out stuff like system identification using forward-mode automatic differentiation ("autodiff" via `AutoDiffXd`, etc.), just to check things like scalability, get a better feel for symbolics and autodiff options in Drake, etc.

As a first steps towards system identification with autodiff, how do I take gradients of `MultibodyPlant` quantities (e.g. generalized forces, forward dynamics, etc.) with respect to inertial parameters (say mass)?

---

- *Note*: Permalinks of Underactuated chapter + notebook at time of writing: [sysid.html](https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/38404d2e0/sysid.html), [sysid.ipynb](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/RussTedrake/underactuated/blob/38404d2e0/sysid.ipynb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drake's formulation of `MultibodyPlant`, in conjunction with the Drake Systems framework, can allow you to take derivatives (via autodiff) with respect to inertial parameters by using the parameter accessors of `RigidBody<T>` on the given plant's `Context<AutoDiffXd>`.

Please see the following tutorial: 
https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/nightly-release/tutorials/multibody_plant_autodiff_mass.ipynb